# Django doesn't accept my form

Tags: django

hi i have a  in template a form generated by a modelForm :

```
    <body>
    <form action="/traitermodificationentrant.html/" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" >

    <legend> Modification du courrier numero {{ cemodifier.id}} </legend>
    <table>
        {{form}}

    </table>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ cemodifier.id}}" name="id">
    <input type="submit" value="modifier"  />

</form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and when i cliked in the button submit the treatment is processed by the view

```
def traiter_modif_entrant(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Form_modif_courrier_Entrant(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ident = form.cleaned_data['id']
        c = Courrier_Entrant.objects.get(id=ident)
        c.reference   = form.cleaned_data['reference']
        c.objet = form.cleaned_data['objet']
        c.categorie =form.clneaned_data['categorie']
        c.expediteur = form.cleaned_data['expediteur']
        c.save()
        HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else :
    form =Form_modif_courrier_Entrant()
return render_to_response('index.html', RequestContext(request,{}) )
```

and my problem is the form is always not valid

thanks in advance!

Comment: what invalid message do you see, what it say?

Comment: What sort of model is it backing? Validity on ModelForms is determined by the clean functions on the individual attributes of the model.

Comment: i don't see an invalid message but the modification of the objects c = Courrier_Entrant.objects.get(id=ident) is not done

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
ident = int(form.cleaned_data['id'])
```

or if that doesn't work, then try "pk" instead:

```
c = Courrier_Entrant.objects.get(pk=ident)
```

Comment: it doesn't work so i think what is wrong is the test if request.method == 'POST': return false because when i add the clause 'else' for this test this is the treatment in the else who are processed

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually passed the form to the template, so it will never show and neither will the errors. The last line of the view should be:

```
return render_to_response('index.html', RequestContext(request,{'form': form}))
```

or, better, using the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: i have already passed the form in the template in a view by doing

Comment: def modif_entrant(request,ident):
    cE         = Courrier_Entrant.objects.get(id=ident)
    ref        = cE.reference
    obj        = cE.objet
    categorie  = cE.categorie
    exp = cE.expediteur
    ModifEntrantFormSet = formset_factory(Form_modif_courrier_Entrant,max_num=1)
    form = ModifEntrantFormSet(initial=[
        {
            'reference' : ref ,
            'objet'     : obj,
            'categorie' : categorie,
            'expediteur': exp,
        }
        ])
    return render_to_response ('traitermodificationentrant.html',{'cemodifier':cE,'form':form }  )

Comment: Well, then you have done things in a very odd way (apart from posting unformatted code in a comment, which is especially odd). Firstly, you are using a formset for a single form. Secondly, you are rendering your initial form in one view but processing it in another, for no good reason. Thirdly, exactly as I say above you're not passing the form back to the template after processing if there are errors, so you'll never see them. Please have a look at the Django docs on using forms in views to see what you should be doing.

Comment: ok @daniel i'm sorry for that and i'm going to take a look to the Django docs